# JSF CDI Bean events on initiation and destruction

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to record the initiation and destruction of JSF CDI sessionscope bean. How can I do it? (The details like user, logged time and log out time needed to be recorded to the database.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose recording creation and destruction of a session scoped bean is not a good idea. For recording the logged in event simply call your logic in the login method or fire a CDI event when the user loggs in successfully. For recording logging out i recommend implementing a HttpSessionListener that gets called when a HttpSession gets invalidated or times out. Don't forget to invalidate the HttpSession in your logout method.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether or not it's a good idea:

Methods annotated with `@PostConstruct`/`@PreDestroy` will be called post construction or pre destruction.

Comment: Thank you. I will adapt this solution and if any issues arise, I will try to implement HttpSessionListner method in above answer.